# Is there a way to use IN and it evaluate values left to right in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Simplified example:

```
select top(1) team.points
from teams
where team.ID = '123' and team.season IN ('2021', '2015', '2010')
```

I have been searching and cannot find a solid answer on this. I want to use the `IN` clause to get certain rows, but I want it to work left to right.

In the example above, I would want a row for 2021, then 2015, then 2010 (assuming no seasons were null).

Is there a way to make the IN clause care about order?

EDIT: So by the comments, I can tell my example was no good. I have edited it to hopefully show what the issue was. I am looking for one result, but I need to check the values in the IN clause IN ORDER, and the actual data in my field was not numerical or easily ordered. In the comments it was suggested to use case statements in the order by clause to make this field where it can be ordered. I was unaware you could use case statements in the order by clause. This seems to have resolved my issue.

Comment: No, but just add an `ORDER BY` clause to your query.

Comment: I thought about that, but the values in my actual use case are not easily ordered. They are not numerical. I guess my example is flawed. Sorry about that.

Comment: The answer is the same though, regardless of how complex the ordering is.

Comment: My example is throwing you off. What I actually need is one result (so TOP), and I need to check for the first value, if its null check for the second value, if its null check for third. So it assigns the first value if its there, if not the second, or the third. I thought about a case statement for this, but I feel like this should work if I can get it to look left to right.

Comment: You could use a `case` _expression_ to determine the order or `join` with a `values` clause to supply pairs of search/order values.

Comment: You're not listening. The **only way** to control the order the data appears is with an `ORDER BY` statement., No matter how many times you want to insist that you want something else, the fact isn't going to change that an `ORDER BY` is the **only way** to control the sort order of the data.

Comment: So how would I ORDER BY strings such as ('2021FALLSEASON', '2015SUMMERSEASON', '2010SPRING')?

Comment: `order by case team_season when '2021FALLSEASON' then 1 when '2015FALLSEASON' then 2 ... else 42 end`

Comment: I did not know that existed! Thank you HABO!

Comment: But also you shouldn't be storing two distinct values in one column

Comment: I agree. My example is flawed. The real data schema is better than my example lol

Comment: `select * from teams as t inner join ( values ( '2021FALLSEASON', 1 ), ( '2015FALLSEASON', 2 ), ... ) as Foo( season, season_order ) on t.season = Foo.season order by season_order;` might be close to functional. Or use a table variable to supply the pairs. Easier to maintain with the pairs in one place rather than scattered about in the `where` and `order by` clauses.

Comment: Habo, can you "answer" this question with the order by with the case statements? That seems to be working great! thank you.

Comment: Note its a case *expression* not a statement.

Comment: Done and _noted_ (again).

Comment: Apologies Dale, stackoverflow english is not my first language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code demonstrates a couple of ways of filtering and ordering the data. Any can be modified to return just `top (1) Points`, but the full output is shown for clarity.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Teams as Table ( Id VarChar(4), Season VarChar(4), Points VarChar(4) );

insert into @Teams ( Id, Season, Points ) values
  ( '1', '2010', 'VC' ), ( '12', '2010', 'CX' ), ( '123', '2010', 'XI' ),
  ( '1', '2015', 'VCI' ), ( '12', '2015', 'CXI' ), ( '123', '2015', 'XII' ),
  ( '1', '2021', 'VCII' ), ( '12', '2021', 'CXII' ), ( '123', '2021', 'XIII' );

select * from @Teams;

-- OP's original query without any explicit order.
select Id, Season, Points
  from @Teams
  where Id = '123' and Season in ( '2021', '2015', '2010' );

-- With order imposed by a   case   expression.
--   For each   Season   the   case   expression needs to be extended to supply an  appropriate value.
select Id, Season, Points
  from @Teams
  where Id = '123' and Season in ( '2021', '2015', '2010' )
  order by case Season
    when '2021' then 1
    when '2015' then 2
    when '2010' then 3
    else 42 end; -- Put unexpected values last.

-- With order and filtering by a   values   clause (equivalent to a separate table).
--   For each   Season   there needs to be an additional row in   Seasons   to specify both the
--     season and its order.  This has the benefit of keeping the pairs of values together.
select T.Id, T.Season, T.Points
  from @Teams as T inner join
    ( values ( '2021', 1 ), ( '2015', 2 ), ( '2010', 3 ) )
    as Seasons( Season, SeasonOrder ) on T.Season = Seasons.Season
  where T.Id = '123'
  order by Seasons.SeasonOrder;
```

Comment: I am using the first method demonstrated with the case expressions, and it works as needed. I understand the logic of the second example, but I personally feel the first option is more self explanatory. In a situation where performance isn't of the highest priority, I like to choose straightforward options (like your first one). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no data to test, I am not sure about the results

Try this:

```
DECLARE     @YearList   TABLE   (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), Year int)
                            --  insert them in the desired order from left to right.
INSERT INTO @YearList   VALUES ('2021'), ('2015'), ('2010'); 

SELECT 
        T.points
FROM    teams       T
JOIN    @YearList   Y   ON  Y.Year = T.season
WHERE   T.ID = '123'
ORDER BY    Y.ID
```